# Concatenate values from the same nodes for each employee individ in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am beginner in programming. I have a scenario like this:
For each unique application member, I want to return a new XML that contains for each EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID all concatenated values of EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION field.
Roles should be concatenated for each MEMBER_UNIQID from APPLICATION_MEMBER nodes.

```
<EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID>
    <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_MAIN_DATA ENTITY="">
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_UNIQ_ID>096788</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_UNIQ_ID>
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_NAME>Dina</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_NAME>
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_SURNAME>Gomez</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_SURNAME>
    </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_MAIN_DATA>
    <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S>

      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA ENTITY="">
        <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>Co-borrower</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>
      </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA>

      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA ENTITY="">          <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>Guarantor</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>
      </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA>


      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA ENTITY="">
        <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>Mortgager individual</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>
      </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA>
    </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S>
  </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID>
```

The output node should be:

```
<EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID>
    <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_MAIN_DATA ENTITY="">
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_UNIQ_ID>096788</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_UNIQ_ID>
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_NAME>Dina</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_NAME>
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_SURNAME>Gomez</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_SURNAME>
    </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_MAIN_DATA>
    <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S>
      <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA ENTITY="">
        <EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>Co-borrower / Guarantor / Mortgager individual</EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION>
      </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA>
    </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S>
  </EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID>
```

My code is:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create A XML Document Of Response String 
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();


            //Read the XML File 

            XmlNodeList nodeList2 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER" +
            "[(EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION ='Borrower' " +
            "or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION='Mortgager' " +
            "or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION='Co-borrower')]");
            List<string> baseMemberUNIQ_IDs = new List<string>();
            List<LoanMember> infos = new List<LoanMember>();



            XmlNodeList baseMembersList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//APPLICATION_MEMBERS/APPLICATION_MEMBER[ROLE='Borrower' or ROLE='Mortgager individual' or ROLE='Co-borrower']");

            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in baseMembersList)
            {
                baseMemberUNIQ_IDs.Add(xmlNode["MEMBER_UNIQ_ID"].InnerText);
            }

            var distinctBaseMembersUNIQ_ID = baseMemberUNIQ_IDs.Distinct();


            foreach (var UNIQ_ID in distinctBaseMembersUNIQ_ID)
            {
                XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER" +
                "[(EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION ='Borrower' " +
                "or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION='Mortgager individual' " +
                "or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION='Co-borrower') " +
                "and EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_MAIN_DATA/EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_UNIQ_ID=" + UNIQ_ID.ToString() + "]");

                foreach (XmlNode xmlNode2 in nodeList)
                {
                    String ROLE = "";
                    foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode2)
                    {
                        ROLE = childNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerXml;
                        Console.WriteLine("CONCATED ROLES ARE " + ROLE);
                        // All roles of each employee individ should be concatenated inside the first node EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION node, Other nodes shoud be removed/
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

In the following url is input document XML: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cb7a26e5

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S = doc.Descendants("EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S").ToList();

            foreach (XElement EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA in EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S)
            {
                string[] roles = EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA.Descendants("EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

                XElement newEMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA = new XElement("EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("ENTITY", ""),
                    new XElement("EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION", string.Join(" / ", roles))
                });

                EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA.ReplaceWith(newEMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How can I filter  nodes which : EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION ='Borrower' or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION ='Co-borrower'  or EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION ='Mortgager Individual'    inside line of code: xDoc
    .Descendants("EMPLOYEE_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA_S");  ?  thank you for your help

Comment: You need to use split0 method and then use contains.